# Rails not working in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I have installed ruby on rails on windows and have ruby installed as well. I know rubygems is working correctly because I installed jekyll with it and jekyll works fine. When I run the following code:

```
rails new myapp
```

I get the following output:

```
      create
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/secrets.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
     run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies............................................
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20151026-12392-101agu7.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make failed, exit code 1
```

Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: It is not about Rails actually. `Failed to build gem native extension`. You need to google how to install `json` gem on windows.

Comment: i have the devkit already installed correctly

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the DevKit build tools because JSON is a native extension. If you used RailsInstaller it should be there. If you used Ruby installer, get it from [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). Just make sure to get the DevKit version that matches your Ruby version. You will have to add the DevKit to your `PATH` a script in the installation directory can do that, or you can do it yourself. More help can be found at: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Also, I suggest the 32 bit edition of Ruby because the 64-bit version has issues with some Gems. It also might be safer to go with Ruby 2.1 or 2.0 at the moment for Gem issues as well.

Comment: Are you sure it is the correct version, be sure to match both the version and the architecture. Also, refer to my last two sentences as 6-bit Ruby 2.2 might have issues with a lot of gems.

Comment: so you are saying to uninstall ruby and install it as the 32 bit version and then reinstall the devkit

Comment: It's not a sure  solution, but I would try it.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users: use rubyinstaller

Development Kit
Detailed guid https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in Windows 10. I even used cygwin and git bash but had similar errors ('make is not recognized... blah blah'). Basically my errors were that I did not extract all of the files in the folder. As soon as I fixed that, the problem was solved.

I'm running an Acer Aspire. First, I downloaded the correct version for my desktop (x64) from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/. Then I ran the installer and extracted them in a folder in my C: drive without any spaces on the folder name.

The ff. files and folders should be extracted to that folder: /bin, /etc, /include, /lib, /mingw, mysys.bat, dk.rb, etc. I checked that they're all there.

Then I ran the instructions according to https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit with 'init' and 'install' After that, I ran the rails command again with the new project and it went through successfully.